# Moving C++ project, errors in atlplus.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to move an old C++ project to VS2010.

The last version of VS to compile it was VS2005, as far as I know. I already fixed a bunch of errors but now I am stuck,

since I am getting errors in `atlplus.h`, which is a `VC10 header file`.

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'CStringW' : undeclared identifier C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlplus.h   692 1


  Error 2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before
  identifier  'strW'    C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlplus.h 692 1


 Error  3   error C3861: 'strW': identifier not found
 C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlplus.h  692 1


 Error  4   error C2065: 'strW' : undeclared identifier C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\atlplus.h 693 1
```

Does anyone have any idea? I've been stuck here since last week.

Comment: Have you tried with/without defining `_UNICODE`?  I don't know why those errors would be thrown from their headers, but it may be worth a shot as it could point you in the right direction if it builds when not looking for unicode types.

Comment: I tried adding #define __UNICODE to the source file, which includes the WinMain function, still the same.

Comment: Not `__UNICODE`. `_UNICODE` (only one _ ).

Comment: Check Character Set parameter in the Project Properties - Configuration Properties - General. Try to set Multibyte or Unicode and see what happens.

Comment: @kjp: Tried it too, same result.

Comment: @AlexFarber: This was set to Multibyte, changing to Unicode seems to solve the problem, now I get a bunch of new errors, which I need to fix obviously.

Comment: @metacircle  Can you also try `#include <atlstr.h>` . Might help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include *atlstr.h* before any headers that use *CString*.
*CString* has been moved to the *atlstr.h* header file.

Comment: So how exactly do I find out where to put this include? The project is pretty big and I just have the task of getting it to compile, never had anything to do with it and I usually come from the .NET world.

Comment: You could try to include it before any of the atlxxx.h includes.

Answer (score 1):

I met the similar problem. please try to include `atlbase.h` instead of `atlstr.h`.

You can see a comment line in file `atlplus.h`:

```
//Avoid using <atlstr.h> except in the registry templates (for circular dependencies).
```